# Error while trying to install Anaconda into Linux: "md5sum mismatch ... Error -3 from inflate: incorrect header check ... fwrite: Bad address"

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I'm trying to install Python into a Linux server which has no internet connection. I downloaded the Anaconda setup for linux to my local machine and transferred it to the server. Then i tried the below command on the command line to start the installation.

```
bash Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After i accepted the license aggreement installation gave me the following error.

```
PREFIX=/home/062212/anaconda3
WARNING: md5sum mismatch of tar archive
expected: 9b6930ed5760ff951b038602552dc7bd
     got: fdd925bf029cafc2674f0b7081629df0  -
Unpacking payload ...
[3140000] Error -3 from inflate: incorrect header check
[3140000] Error decompressing Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.abi3.so
Failed to write all bytes for Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.abi3.so
fwrite: Bad address
[3140004] Error -3 from inflate: incorrect header check
[3140004] Error decompressing Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.abi3.so
Failed to write all bytes for Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.abi3.so
fwrite: Bad address
```

My aim is to install python and all necessary dependencies on this server and to automatically run the scripts I wrote on my local machine on this server at certain time intervals.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (Ootpa) is installed on the server.

This is my first time using linux and when I searched the web I couldn't find a solution. How can I continue?

Answer (score 0):

It shows, that the hash of the file (md5sum) does not match with the expected hash. This could be because the file got somehow corrupted. You can check the hash directly with the following command while being in the folder the file is located in:

```
tail -n +601 Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh | md5sum
```

Execute this command with the file you downloaded and with the file on the server.

If the hash is valid (9b6930ed5760ff951b038602552dc7bd) for your downloaded file but not valid for the file on the server than probably something went wrong while copying the file. Then we would need some more information how you transferred the file to the server exactly.

If the hash for the downloaded file is already invalid, then try downloading it again or get it from somewhere else.